# receiving a json string in C# Web Api 2

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to do a patch with web api. I keep getting NULL for my json. Please Help

Here is my Json

[{"PartNumber":"AN33016UA-VB"}{"Category":"Chassis"}]

Here is my my class

```
public class wsCategory
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Api Controller

```
[HttpPatch]
[ActionName("IMDSCategory")]
public HttpResponseMessage IMDSCategory([FromBody]wsCategory jsonbody)
{
    var data = jsonbody.PartNumber;

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Comment: Can we see _how_ you're calling the service as well? (I'd love to take for granted the PATCH is being called correctly, but...well, you're here.)

Comment: Im using chrome advanced rest client. My content type is application/json. If that answers your questioin

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is inavalid.

`[{"PartNumber":"blahblah","Category":"Chassis"}]`

I believe the array container will be parsed out correctly, but I'm on a chromebook right now, so I can't check that. If it still fails, drop the `[]`.

Comment: I don't think the array container will parse correctly as it's contents are malformed JSON

Comment: You misunderstand. *My* JSON array is just a single element array. I believe json.net will parse that to a single object, but I could be remembering that incorrectly and it might parse to a single element IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

based on your method

```
[HttpPatch]
[ActionName("IMDSCategory")]
public HttpResponseMessage IMDSCategory([FromBody]wsCategory jsonbody){...}
```

Your JSON is invalid given the model you are trying to parse.

```
[{"PartNumber":"AN33016UA-VB"}{"Category":"Chassis"}]
```

should be

```
{"PartNumber":"AN33016UA-VB","Category":"Chassis"}
```